# why php artisan in lumen not working?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

When I run `php artisan migrate` the result is

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]   Class 'Memcached' not found

Is there anyway to enable this command?

For additional information, I created my project under centos 7 and php 7 version.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659035/php-memcached-fatal-error-class-memcache-not-found

Comment: run `yum -y install php-pecl-memcache`

Comment: you haven't install Memcached yet in your OS

Comment: i had runing "yum -y install php-pecl-memcache" and the result is "Error: php70w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Memcache extension with PHP 7 on CentOS fails to install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37550910/memcache-extension-with-php-7-on-centos-fails-to-install)

Answer (score 2):

1. You are missing memcached on your system
2. It is not mandatory, if you just want to have the system up and running

Edit your `.env` file and change your cache driver to `file`

```
CACHE_DRIVER=file
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem with lumen 5.5.2 then found that config/cache.php was missing following code:

```
 'array' => [
            'driver' => 'array',
        ],

        'file' => [
            'driver' => 'file',
            'path'   => storage_path('framework/cache/data'),
        ],
```

After adding above code, it works well.

Happy coding